# The stream or file could not be opened

Tags: php, linux, logging, permissions, activecollab

got a few bug on my project. I'm using ActiveCollab and logs are saying that, but my "/var/www/ac/logs" is 777 and after many try my entire "/var/www/ac/activecollab" became 777 too. How could it be a permission error when 777 is enable everywhere ?

```
2018/04/12 08:02:05 [error] 8543#8543: *48 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/ac/logs/log-2018-04-12.txt" could not be opened: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/ac/activecollab/5.11.0/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/ac/activecollab/5.11.0/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(107): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/ac/activecollab/5.11.0/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)
#2 /var/www/ac/activecollab/5.11.0/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#3 /var/www/ac/activecollab/5.11.0/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(517): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(200, 'Request {signat...', Array)
#4 /var/www/ac/activecollab/5.11.0/vendor/activecollab/logger/src/Logger.php(204): Monolog\Logger->log(200, 'Request {signat" while reading response header from upstream, client: 109.190.129.211, server: projet.minecompany.fr, request: "GET /api/v1/user-session HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "projet.minecompany.fr", referrer: "http://projet.minecompany.fr/"
```

Comment: The error is `chmod(): Operation not permitted` which means the PHP process is not allowed to execute `chmod`. This again can have several reasons, like a disabled method in PHP or the fastcgi process running in a chroot environment without `chmod`, or…